# symfony2 how to register bundles not installed throught composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a bundle which I had to clone from a private repo, and cloned it from the `vendor` directory, and registered the bundle in the `AppKernel.php` now, I am getting an error that says, `PHP fatal error: Class 'foo\foobar\example not found in C:\... AppKernel.php`

So, my question is how do I make sure, pacakges not installed through composer get registered in the autoloader

Comment: why not use composer to clone your private repo ? works for me -> [docs here](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be not to pull manualy from your private repo, but use composer also in this case.

To accomplish this, you will need a private composer repository - like one with [satis](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md).

If that is not an option for any reason, you can configure the autoloader in your project /composer.json like this:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyVendor\\MyBundleBundle": "vendor/foo",
        }
    },
    ....
}
```

But I strongly recommend the satis way.

Comment: I know that is the best, way. but the package is not yet in pacakgist, or any other online repository.

Comment: satis can be a *private* repository - not online like packagist

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do it, just a simple approach

Comment: I posted a simple approach to modify the autoloader above. Even its not a good practise, it should work. Another way: http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs